# 'HTTP error 500' when increasing 'upload_max_filesize' and 'post_max_size' from 'php.ini'

Tags: php, xampp

I am using XAMPP server on my Windows 10 and developing on Laravel 5.7, I want to upload images up to 10mb in size but by default php allows only up to 2mb. So I tried to update my php.ini file as described in the title, but when I tried to submit the for it gave me 'HTTP error 500'.

(I changed 'upload_max_filesize' from 2M to 1024M and 'post_max_size' from 8M to 1024M).

I am using: Laravel5.7, PHP7.3.1, XAMPP3.2.2

[shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdyfD.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2BcP.png)

[xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSxSE.png)

Comment: Put in your page `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see what kind of error are you receiving. Check if the .ini changes are effective.  `php -ini | grep upload
`

Comment: Yeah the .ini changes are effective and error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE) have no effect :(

Comment: Having you tried restarting the services? You may need to restart Apache, or PHP-FPM (if you are running PHP as FPM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to increase the file size upload limit.

If using on a local machine using XAMPP, we will find the **php.ini** in the following locations.
**Windows:  C:\xampp\php\php.ini**

Open the php.ini file. Find these lines in the php.ini file and replace it following numbers

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Save the changes and refresh your website and try uploading the file again. and Don't forget to restart your XAMPP Apache server

---

**NOTE:** For Windows, you can find the file in the C:\xampp\php\php.ini-Folder (Windows) or in the etc-Folder (within the xampp-Folder).